# Python organzing default values as objects

Tags: python, django

I have a django application that is utilizing a third party API and needs to receive several arguments such as `client_id`, `user_id` etc. I currently have these values labeled at the top of my file as variables, but I'd like to store them in an object instead.

My current set up looks something like this:

```
user_id = 'ID HERE'
client_id = 'ID HERE'
api_key = 'ID HERE'

class Social(LayoutView, TemplateView):
    def grab_data(self):
       authenticate_user = AuthenticateService(client_id, user_id)
```

I want the default values set up as an object

```
SERVICE_CONFIG = {
    'user_id': 'ID HERE',
    'client_id': 'ID HERE'
}
```

So that I can access them in my classes like so:

```
 authenticate_user = AuthenticateService(SERVICE_CONFIG.client_id, SERVICE_CONFIG.user_id)
```

I've tried `SERVICE_CONFIG.client_id`, and `SERVICE_CONFIG['client_id']`, as well as setting up the values as a mixin but I can't figure out how to access them any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is not Javascript. That's a dictionary, not an object. You access dictionaries using the item syntax, not the attribute syntax:

```
AuthenticateService(SERVICE_CONFIG['client_id'], SERVICE_CONFIG['user_id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class, an instance, or a function object to store data as properties:

```
class ServiceConfig:
    user_id = 1
    client_id = 2

ServiceConfig.user_id   # => 1

service_config = ServiceConfig()

service_config.user_id  # => 1

service_config = lambda:0

service_config.user_id = 1
service_config.client_id = 2

service_config.user_id  # => 1
```

Normally using a dict is the simplest way to store data, but in some cases higher readability of property access can be preferred, then you can use the examples above. Using a lambda is the easiest way but more confusing for someone reading your code, therefore the first two approaches are preferable.